# How can I write shorter code by using loops in a board game

Tags: java, computer-science

I write code for 'X' and 'o' game now everything works fine but I want to optimize my code and make my functions shorter for example

I planned the game so the player play against the computer and the priorities of the computer would be to win first, then to block the opponent and eventually to fill the empty cells
So I wrote a function to column, function for row and function for diagonals, and used many conditions
I wanted to know if you have any idea how to shorten the code by using loops or perhaps with additional functions
for example theat function checking if  the computer can win by 3 in a row

```
    public static  boolean ComuterrowWin(char [][] board){
        if((board[0][0]=='O' && board[0][1]=='O') && board[0][2]!='X'){
            board[0][2]='O'; return true;}
        else if((board[0][1]=='O' && board[0][2]=='O') && board[0][0]!='X'){
            board[0][0]='O'; return true;}
        else if((board[0][0]=='O' && board[0][2]=='O') && board[0][1]!='X'){
            board[0][1]='O'; return true;}
        else if((board[1][0]=='O' && board[1][1]=='O') && board[1][2]!='X'){
            board[1][2]='O'; return true;}
        else if((board[1][1]=='O' && board[1][2]=='O' && board[1][0]!='X')){
            board[1][0]='O'; return true;}
        else if((board[1][0]=='O' && board[1][2]=='O') && board[1][1]!='X'){
            board[1][1]='O'; return true;}
        else if((board[2][0]=='O' && board[2][1]=='O') && board[2][2]!='X'){
            board[2][2]='O'; return true;}
        else if((board[2][1]=='O' && board[2][2]=='O') && board[2][0]!='X'){
            board[2][0]='O'; return true;}
        else if((board[2][0]=='O' && board[2][2]=='O') && board[2][1]!='X'){
            board[2][1]='O'; return true;}
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: May be better to ask here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the data structure, you can try this. Simply organize at least the rows into a loop:

```
public static  boolean ComuterrowWin(char [][] board){
    for (int row=0; row<=2; row++) {
        if((board[row][0]=='O' && board[row][1]=='O') && board[row][2]!='X'){
            board[row][2]='O'; return true;}
        if((board[row][1]=='O' && board[row][2]=='O') && board[row][0]!='X'){
            board[row][0]='O'; return true;}
        if((board[row][0]=='O' && board[row][2]=='O') && board[row][1]!='X'){
            board[row][1]='O'; return true;}
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: great! i would like to see more options please

Answer (score 2):

Okay :-). What about this one ?

```
public static  boolean ComuterrowWin(char [][] board){
    for (int row=0; row<=2; row++) {
        for (int col=0; col<=2; col++) {
            if((board[row][(col+1)%3]=='O' && board[row][(col+2)%3]=='O') && board[row][col]!='X'){
                board[row][col]='O'; return true;}
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why wrong? The modulo operator produces just the numbers needed. For col=1 they will be 2 and 0.

Comment: But none of the conditions have {2, 0, 1} as a check. See OP's list of condtions for true. The second column doesn't start with 2 anywhere.

Comment: Right, but there is a {0, 2, 1} check, and having && operators it is equivalent with {2, 0, 1}. The condition represents "there is no 'O' in the current column, but there is 'O' in the other two". The order of the other two is irrelevant.

Comment: It fails, as it should fail for a 'O' 'O' 'X' row. This is not a winner situation.

Comment: Got it cleared. Damn, I had taken the last one to be ==. Careless mistake. Thx. for clarifying. Just edit your post for Edit's sake(fake/dummy edit) and I shall reverse the downvote because it doesn't allow me to upvote unless post is edited at all.

Comment: And, clever solution!

Answer (score 1):

Adapting @galcoholic 's answer, how about this,

```
public static  boolean ComuterrowWin(char [][] board){
        int[][] win = {{0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 1}};
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                if((board[row][win[i][0]]=='O' && board[row][win[i][1]]=='O') && board[row][win[i][2]]!='X'){
                    board[row][win[i][2]]='O';
                    return true;}
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: can I do the same with the diagonals I thought maybe keep the values of the diagonals in an array and then make the conditions something like this:`public static boolean ComdiagonalgWin(char [][] board){
 char[]mainDig= new char [3];
 for (int row=0; row<=board.length; row++) {
 for (int col=0; col<=board.length; col++) {
   if(row==col){
    for (int x=0; x<=board.length; x++) {
     mainDig[x]=board[row][col];
     System.out.println( mainDig);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}`

Comment: @MarcoPolo : So, do you want to check if the diagonals have certain values stored and check for them? I mean, if diagonal has, board[0][0] = '0', board[1][1] = '0' and board[2][2] = 'X' then you want to check this for both the diagonals at a time? Is this what you want?

Comment: @MarcoPolo : See my other answer for the diagonal problem. Also, there is a small correction in my answer above. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the diagonal problem, here is how I suggest you do it,

```
public static  boolean ComdiagonalgWin(char [][] board){

        // For main diagonal, x_index = y_index
        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
            if((board[row % 3][row % 3] == 'O' && board[(row + 1) % 3][(row + 1) % 3]=='O') && board[(row + 2) % 3][(row + 2) % 3]!='X')
                board[(row + 2) % 3][(row + 2) % 3] = 'O'; return true;
        }
        // For other diagonal, x_index + y_index = 2(or the number of rows you have - 1)
        for(int row = 0, col = 2; row < 3 && col >= 0; row++, col--){
            if((board[row % 3][col % 3] == 'O' && board[(row + 1) % 3][(col + 1) % 3]=='O') && board[(row + 2) % 3][(col + 2) % 3]!='X')
                board[(row + 2) % 3][(col + 2) % 3] = 'O'; return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

You can see that the post-increment operator uses the value *unincremented* first at the place of increment and the increment then happens. The incremented value will be used in the next use of variable which is how I have done it in both the cases.

Comment: ok, i tried it but eclipse shows me it's going out of the array bound:"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:" there is a way to fix it?

Comment: @MarcoPolo : You probably have different board limit. Can you post the code and tell me the line it is going OutOfBoundsException ?

Comment: the board is on size 3X3 and I think the problem is in the second diagonal when the computer play he try first to fill row and col and then the diagonal and when I block him in the num 3 the system throw the exception. I don't know how to post code in comment I have already tried many times can you explain to me

Comment: @MarcoPolo : You can paste you code here, create a paste and then post here. Use https://pastebin.com

Comment: that what I tried and work good but I want to make it in more smart and short way https://pastebin.com/9PbbxYk4

Comment: @MarcoPolo : This is as short as its gonna go. Trying to make it even shorter will result(if possible, I don't know) will result in unreadable code. Check the edited answer.